# Where is the official podcast DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd, podcast

The [podcast howto](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html) on the Apple website shows a sample XML file, which refers to a podcast DTD: `podcast-1.0.dtd`.  The DTD is not available at this address, unfortunately.  I heard you can validate a feed using feedvalidator.org, but it's only a service.  Is there any other location where the official podcast DTD is available?

The DTD is given as `xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"`. This URL does not actually resolve to a DTD.

Comment: If you look at [the Atom spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4287.txt), you'll see "This specification does not define a DTD for Atom Documents". I suspect the same is true of the iTunes spec.

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd Also this is the best itunes documation I've found: http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#summary

Comment: This seems to define DTD from Apple: https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itcb54353390

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**no dtd** is referenced by the xml attribute you are quoting. instead it is but a (abstract) namespace declaration - syntactically it could be any valid uri as the local name (`itunes`) could be any id (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-NCName) for a formal definition). semantically it represents a particular markup vocabulary. no concrete resource needs to be accessible through the uri.

a dtd reference would have to come as part of a doctype declaration at the beginning of your xml doc, see the [formal spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-doctypedecl) or a  [gentler explanation](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

note that though the examples' discussion limits itself on (x)html-related documents, any xml doc may have a dtd defined.

regards

Comment: This explains why we don't have to expect to find the DTD for Apple's RSS 2.0 flavour via the URL specified in `xmlns:itunes`. But it does not answer the original question: Where is the official podcast DTD? Or a related question: Where can I find an XML grammar (DTD, XSD, ...) which specifies Apple's RSS 2.0 format and which I can use for validating those feeds?

Comment: Indeed while there is nothing technically incorrect about this answer it doesn't answer any of the questions the OP had, such as where to find a DTD, or why the documentation says that a DTD should be available at that URL but it isn't (quote "The namespace declaration points to a document that defines the iTunes Store tags")

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe there is an 'official' podcast DTD that is accessible.

There are unofficial specs put out by various private companies/organisations that run podcast directories (e.g. Apple, Google, Spotify). But, at this time (March 2020), there doesn't appear to be any such published podcast DTD.

The following resources may help...

### Official Generic RSS Spec

For information about the general rss feed specification, see the following:

[Official RSS Spec](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification)

### Unofficial Commercial Specs

For information about podcast-specific rss feed specifications, see the following:

[Apple Podcasts Connect Help](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itcb54353390)

[Google Feed Requirements](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/podcast/rss-feed)

[Spotify Podcast Delivery Specification](https://podcasters.spotify.com/terms/Spotify_Podcast_Delivery_Specification_v1.6.pdf)

---

There are also online services where you can post a URL to your podcast rss feed and check they are valid against some of the above-mentioned specs...

I recently posted [details about such validators in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60586619/4347889).