# Podcast Validator and giving the audio file

Tags: podcast

I am new to Podcast and I am looking for some podcast validator which will tell if the podcast url is valid and the audio object.

For example

https://anchor.fm/123123XYZ/rss

https://libsyn.com/ABCXZ/rss

if there is no audio, it should return with some error and if there is an audio enclosure, it should return with the audio url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try either of these two resources...

https://podba.se/validate/

https://castfeedvalidator.com/

They allow you to enter in the URL of your podcast rss feed. They will then parse (go through) the feed and check that each of its elements is valid.